# Draw pictures using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to draw pictures using VBA code?

Specifically, one of the pictures I would like to draw, is a right triangle.
The three lines should be fixed-connected at the corners. The user will then type the angle of the bottom corner in Excel cell and the triangle's hypotenuse slope should be adjusted accordingly.  Also, height and length can also be parameters, which will be used to draw the triangle to relative scale.
[image]

Comment: You should investigate the Shape Object which should do everything you seek.

Comment: Macro record for a "Right triangle" shape gives the shape name constant, and the arguments required (Position on the sheet, and height and length)-

Comment: Did exactly that. I'm taking a look now. Thanks!

Comment: +1 @user3548534. Tinker with that code and if you have questions specifically I am sure someone can help. Just show the code you're using and describe where you're stuck!